# How to restrict access to SOLR Specific Pages such as "Core Admin"?

Tags: tomcat, solr

I can't restrict access to SOLR's "Core Admin" page which comes in the main page of SOLR web console.(Located at the left hand side menu). I followed the SOLR Security wiki page tutorials to enable login based authentication in Apache Tomcat 7. Then in my SOLR's web.xml file, I added the following url pattern elements:

```
...
<url-pattern>/select/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/#/~cores/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/update/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattenr>/collection1/*</url-pattern>
...
```

Then when I go the "Core Admin" page in my browser window, it does not ask for any credentials. What would be the cause of this problem?

Comment: # urls are never seen by the webserver - anything with # is browser specific, and you won't be able to block it on the server side. See the server log for the actual resource being requested by the browser (the admin interface is a javascript application that makes requests behind the scenes).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I checked the Tomcat's access logs and find the following related to requesting the core admin page:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2015:21:59:49 +0300] "GET /solr/admin/cores?wt=json&_=1436122789842 HTTP/1.1" 200 862
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jul/2015:21:59:49 +0300] "GET /solr/admin/cores?wt=json&_=1436122789864 HTTP/1.1" 200 862
127.0.0.1 - admin [05/Jul/2015:21:59:49 +0300] "GET /solr/tpl/cores.html?_=1436122789875 HTTP/1.1" 200 6973
```

Comment: Blocking /solr/admin is probably the way to go, then (and you should probably update the question with that information and submit the working solution as your answer and accept it).

Comment: Actually as the question title says I want to block access to only one page not the whole. I tried "/solr/admin" before however it completely blocks access to Solr main page.